# Running Octave tasks from Python

Tags: python, subprocess, octave, message-queue, oct2py

I have a pretty complex computation code written in Octave and a python script which receives user input, and needs to run the Octave code based on the user inputs. As I see it, I have these options:

1. Port the Octave code to python.
2. Use external libraries (i.e. oct2py) which enable you to run the Octave/Matlab engine from python.
3. Communicate between a python process and an octave process. One such possibility would be to use subprocess from the python code and wait for the answer.

Since I'm pretty reluctant to port my code to python and I don't want to rely on maintenance of external libraries such as oct2py, I am in favor of option 3. However, since the system should scale well,  I do not want to spawn a new octave process for every request, and a tasks queue system seems more reasonable. Is there any (recommended) tasks queue system to enqueue tasks in python and have an octave worker on the other end process it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way it is described here, option 3 degenerates to option 2 because Octave does not have an obvious way (an API or package) for the 'Octave worker' to connect to a task queue.

The [only way](http://octave.sourceforge.net/packages.php) Octave does "networking" is by [the sockets package](http://octave.sourceforge.net/sockets/index.html) and this means implementing the protocol for communicating with the task queue from scratch (in Octave).

The original motivation for having an 'Octave worker' is to have the main process of Octave launch once and then "direct it" to execute functions and return results, rather than launching the main process of Octave for every call to a function.

Since Octave cannot do 'a worker' (that [launches, listens to a 'channel' and executes code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish%E2%80%93subscribe_pattern)) out of the box, the only other way to achieve this is to have the task queue framework all work in Python and only call Octave when you need its functionality, most likely via `oct2py` (i.e. option 2).

There are many different ways to do this ranging from [Redis](http://redis.io/topics/pubsub), to [PyPubSub](http://pubsub.sourceforge.net/installation.html), [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/) and [RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/). All of them straightforward and very well documented. PyPubSub does not require any additional components.

(Just as a note: The solution of having [an 'executable' octave script](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Executable-Octave-Programs.html), [calling it via Python and blocking until it returns](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) is not as bad as it sounds however and [for some parallel-processing frameworks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9956898/how-to-use-matlab-code-in-mapper-hadoop/9976984#9976984) it is the only way to have multiple copies of the same Octave script operate on different data segments.)

Answer (score 0):

All three options are reasonable depending on your particular case.

> I don't want to rely on maintenance of external libraries such as oct2py,  I am in favor of option 3

`oct2py` is implemented using option 3. You can reinvent what it already does or use it directly. `oct2py` is pure Python and it has permissive license: if its development were to stop tomorrow; you could include its code alongside yours.